# Jquery ajax success function not executed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Jquery ajax success function not executed?

*json*

Here is the json output from /controll/operation.php?p=demo

```
{"message-count":"1","messages":[{"to":"3321313","status":"6","error-text":"Unroutable message - rejected","network":"MV-FIXED"}]}
```

This is a valid json checked from jason validator.

*javascript code*

```
$('#send').click(function()
           {
       var to = $('#to').val();
       var sender = $('#sender').val();
       var message = $('#message').val();
       if (to == "") {
       $("#forto").addClass("has-error");
            return false;
            }
       if (sender == "") {
            $("#forsender").addClass("has-error");
            return false;
            }
        if (message == "") {
             $("#formessage").addClass("has-error");
            return false;
            }
        $("#send").prop( "disabled", true );
        $("#alert").html('<img style="display:block;margin:0 auto 0 auto;" src="../images/loading.gif">');

            $.ajax("../controll/operation.php?p=demo", {
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                dataType: "json",
                data: { "to": to, "sender": sender, "message": message},
                success: function (response) {

                var table = '<div align="center">';

                    for (var i = 0; i < response.messages.length; i++)
                    {
                        var status = response.messages[i].status;
                        var to = response.messages[i].to;
                        var messageprice = response.messages[i].messageprice;
                        var remainingbalance = response.messages[i].remainingbalance;
                        var errortext = response.messages[i].errortext;

                        if(status == "0")
                        {
                            status = "Message sent successfully to ";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            status = errortext;
                        }
                        table = table + '<p>'+status+to+'</p>';

                    }

                    table = table + '</div>';

                    $("#alert").html(table);
                    $("#send").prop( "disabled", false);

                },
        error: function (header, status, error) {
                console.log('ERROR' + header + ' ' + status + ' ' + error);
            }
            });

});
```

*browser console output*

```
ERROR[object Object] parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Comment: check for bad character  in response

Comment: did you check the http status code? it should be 200 to trigger success

Comment: @thedjaney No.I didn't check da status code.how to check http status code?

Comment: @Ravi Is there any bad character did you notice in the  code?

Comment: open a console and see network tab. in chrome (windows) press f12

Comment: If you want to retrieve JSON object from your operation.php, try to use getJson instead. I don't know if it'll solve your problem but it might be more efficiant and more readable. Here is the doc http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: @thedjaney status 200 is ok

Comment: another thing to try is do not use $.ajax, and use $.post instead.

Comment: @user3567684 have you tried "stringifying" the data you post? i.e. data: JSON.stringify({ "to": to, "sender": sender, "message": message })

Comment: problem solved with the same js code by changing the json encoding php function "return" to "echo"

Thanks for all who commented :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the response text as JSON object. See the below example.

```
var jsonData = '{"message-count":"1","messages":[{"to":"3321313","status":"6","error-text":"Unroutable message - rejected","network":"MV-FIXED"}]}';

var data = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
$.each(data.messages, function(i, item) {
    alert(item.to);
    alert(item.status);
});
```

However, `error-text` is not getting accessed as it contain a special character in it. so better to rename it from server side as `errortext`;